# Is it possible to use drop by with in/to/on

Tags: verbs

Are these possible?

I dropped by in a shop on my way home.

I dropped by to a shop on my way home.

I dropped by on a shop on my way home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Drop by" is a phrasal verb that works as is.  Adding another preposition only makes the sentence confusing.

Examples:

> I want to **drop by** your house after work to give you your Christmas present.
>
> She said she was going to **drop by** the shop to see if they'd finished repairing her car.
>
> Let's **drop by** a flower shop on the way to Mom's to get her something nice.

Side note:  If you want to say "*a* shop" then you should specify *what kind* of shop, otherwise it's too general.  However, if you say "*the* shop", then you expect the listener will understand which specific shop you mean.  In the above example, it should be obvious that "the shop" means either *"the car repair shop we normally use"* or *"the car repair shop where she took her car for service"*.

Comment: A typo in your answer I think. 'Preposition', not 'pronoun' in the first line.

Comment: Thank you. It's not necessary, but is it possible?

Comment: @user1425  No, it would be confusing.  I wouldn't understand what you were trying to say.